# Makefile: Linking .*a library

Tags: c, linux, linker, makefile, dynamic-library

DESCRIPTION:
I have a library libshell.a, inside of it is the function ord_interna that i'm attempting to use, however it seems i linked it wrong, could you guys fix my error, so i dont make it in the future? Cheers,

Error:

```
/tmp/ccn5lbmJ.o: In function `main':
minishell.c:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `ord_interna'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [minishell.o] Error 1
```

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -c

all: microshell

microshell: minishell.o
    gcc minishell.o -o microshell

minishell.o: minishell.c
    gcc minishell.c minishell.h entrada_minishell.c entrada_minishell.h ejecutar.c ejecutar.h libshell.a

clean:
    rm -rf *o microshell
```

Comment: Wow, that makefile is weird.

Comment: Its at the end of gcc for minishell.o, how to fix it in that case? I'm sorry I'm just ot used to using makefiles, I'm usually coding in Win, however this time I'm forced to do it.

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas You don't seem to be understanding why libraries and linking are necessary nor how they work. I suggest you google "C compilation process" and then you'll know where this has gone wrong.

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas In the second gcc line, remove the headers (.h) and try using -l as the switch before 'shell' (instead of libshell.a).  Better yet, find another Makefile from some other code that correctly links in a static library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your makefile, I'm guessing you have these source files:

```
minishell.c
entrada_minishell.c
ejecutar.c
```

And that you want to compile them, and then link them all together with `libshell.a` to create an executable called `microshell`.  In that case, you want something like:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic

all: microshell

microshell: minishell.o entrada_minishell.o ejecutar.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -L. -lshell
```

You can add a `clean` target if you want, but just that should get you going.

Editorial notes:

1. it's really weird to put header files on the compilation line; I assumed you didn't actually want to do that.
2. You should look into gcc's `-MMD` flag to do automatic dependency generation.